# How to create a two sided ticks labels grid in layout (ArcMap)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layouts, grids-graticules

I'm making a planing map. I want to add to the final layout a specific  kind of grid:
The grid needs to be with a 6 character label that is separated in to two labels. Each one of the labels needs to be from both side of the grid's outer ticks. Like this example:
[image]

I've tried to change almost all of grid's properties but still could not able to figure out how to do it.
[image]

My result so far isn't satisfying:
[image]

It's important to say that I **do not** have the ArcGIS Production Mapping extension.
Is there any way to create this kind of grid without this extension? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got some workaround for this question:

1. Make a separate neatline for your data frame; make sure it's not grouped with the data frame.
2. Modify your data frame's grid that it will have long enough ticks that'll reach the neatline. 
   [image]
3. Convert your grid into graphics; all the grid's features (ticks, labels, grids etc) comes as element group - ungroup it.
   [image]
4. Now yo can handle your labels as elements (rotate them and so on).

[image]

Be aware that this solution isn't suitable with large grids or DDP project because it's really a time-consuming job.